# How to perform a digital signature on Smartcard with prestored hash

Tags: digital-signature, smartcard, sha, apdu

I am trying to use a smart card to perform a digital signature, my issue is when I try these set of commands:

```
Select Application: 00A4040410E828BD080F*********
Verify Pin: 0020008506*******
Set SE for CRT HT: 002241AA03800110
Set SE for CRT DST: 002241b606800112840105
Store Hash: 002a90a00890008004AAAAAAAA // AAAAAAAA are Just a random 4 bytes for the card to compute then store
Sign: 002a9e9a00
```

I can not sign neither by setting the security environment to CRT-DST nor CRT-HT, with the former it returns 6a88(SE problem) and the latter returns 6a95(Hash not found).
I am following IAS_ECC_v1.0.1 to the book but it is not clear which security environment to use in case of setting the hash then signing. I tried the commands for SHA-256 as well but same result.

I am used to setting the security environment then performing the digital signature but this is the first time I encounter the prestored hash type of card.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify at least some issues: What you are describing is not a *precomputed hash*, but an *intermediate hash value*, as typically applied in the scheme, where the card has at least some influence in the hash computation. It is supposed to update the given intermediate hash by considering the last data bytes given. This is a sort of middle point between the card hashing all the input data (possible, but due to limited I/O bandwith seldom attractive) and providing the final hash value from the outside (no influence by the card).

Such an intermediate hash requires in DO 90 the intermediate hash value concatenated with a bit counter, which is 8 bytes long. For SHA-256 this would mean 40 bytes (32 bytes hash followed by bit counter). This is combined with DO 80 giving the final data.

Your example (*store hash* is at least a misleading term), provides the DO 90 as empty, however, contradicting the intention of an intermediate hash.